# at-rules not working in visual studio

Tags: css

So I'm using code from this link:
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/pure-css3-animated-clouds-background

Which contains:

```
@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
```

And it's causing this error:

[image: Error]

---

> "Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: "-" is not valid at the start of a code block. 
>   Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 185:    } Line 186: Line 187:    @-o-keyframes moveclouds { Line
>   188:        0% { Line 189:            margin-left: 1000px;"

If I remove the "at-rules" it'll work just fine; however, the clouds won't move.

Answer (score 6):

Since Visual Studio's "@" sign indicates the beginning of .net code in a CSHTML file, one needs to double the "@" sign to cancel it out. Like so:

```
@@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
```

However, if you add the CSS code in the CSS file, one "@" sign will work, like so:

```
@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
        0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
        100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in witch file you store the css?
all working fine http://jsfiddle.net/jsbot/cr5g6580/
copy to index.html file

```
<div id="clouds">
    <div class="cloud x1"></div>
    <!-- Time for multiple clouds to dance around -->
    <div class="cloud x2"></div>
    <div class="cloud x3"></div>
    <div class="cloud x4"></div>
    <div class="cloud x5"></div>
</div>
```

and to style.css

```
/*Lets start with the cloud formation rather*/

/*The container will also serve as the SKY*/

*{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
    /*To hide the horizontal scroller appearing during the animation*/
    overflow: hidden;
}

#clouds{
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: #c9dbe9;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
    background: -linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
}

/*Time to finalise the cloud shape*/
.cloud {
    width: 200px; height: 60px;
    background: #fff;

    border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;

    position: relative; 
}

.cloud:before, .cloud:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; 
    background: #fff;
    width: 100px; height: 80px;
    position: absolute; top: -15px; left: 10px;

    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cloud:after {
    width: 120px; height: 120px;
    top: -55px; left: auto; right: 15px;
}

/*Time to animate*/
.x1 {
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
}

/*variable speed, opacity, and position of clouds for realistic effect*/
.x2 {
    left: 200px;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    transform: scale(0.6);
    opacity: 0.6; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    /*Speed will also be proportional to the size and opacity*/
    /*More the speed. Less the time in 's' = seconds*/
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

.x3 {
    left: -250px; top: -200px;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

.x4 {
    left: 470px; top: -250px;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
    transform: scale(0.75);
    opacity: 0.75; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
}

.x5 {
    left: -150px; top: -150px;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
```